# Can't group focus selector css

Tags: css

I am trying to override the thumb box-shadow for the different browsers, but for some reason when I group them, none of it gets applied. If I removed the other selectors, it works fine. Any thoughts

```
input[type='range']:focus::-webkit-slider-thumb,
input[type='range']:focus::-ms-thumb,
input[type='range']:focus::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: purple;
}
```

Expect css box-shadow rule to apply to all the selectors. Result: the rule doesn't get applied at all.

Comment: maybe because they are on a new line? Im just guessing :)

Comment: Can you use the HTML/CSS snippet (Ctrl-M) to show a working example of what you are trying to achieve?